# What are the rules for how SwiftUI preview works?

Tags: swiftui

The SwiftUI preview feature in Xcode is one of my favorite things about SwiftUI.

But I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how Xcode runs my code to generate a preview, and at what point it stops executing my code. It's definitely running my code, because it compiles and my changes apply to the preview, including conditional logic.

But if I include a timer or a network request, it looks like Xcode doesn't update the preview unless I press the Live Preview button or actually run the app in the simulator.

Could anyone explain how SwiftUI preview works, and what the exact difference is between Live Preview and regular preview?

Answer (score 0):

**Preview mode** just perform one-pass rendering of view structs "as-is", ie. having default or initial values. That's why only static info is shown.

**Live Preview** runs some variant of simulator, launches your application as a context and injects in it current PreviewProvider. That's why all run-time features work.